# Reading jpg rating metadata on windows

Tags: python, windows, image, image-processing, metadata

I'm trying to iterate through the photos on a folder tree on my Windows box and build a list of all the files in that folder tree. As I do that I'd like to filter the list to only grab the files that have a certain "rating" in the metadata (e.g. only files that are 3 stars or more).

I've tried using PIL but I can't figure out where that rating metadata is kept. It doesn't seem to be in the EXIF data or in info()

Comment: While I can't help the programming part, I do know where Windows will get the ratings values. There are four places that Windows will get ratings data from.  In the EXIF group, there is tag `0x4746`/`Rating` and tag `0x4749`/`RatingPercent`.  There is also two matching tags in the XMP group, `Rating` and `RatingPercent`.  Windows will read any of these from a file and will write all four if edited under Properties->Details.

Comment: @StarGeek Thanks. I was able to extract the EXIF data and it wasn't in there. Your comment sent me on the right track. Opening a sample jpg in an editor and searching for XMP confirmed that the rating data is there. Now I have to write the code to extract that properly as PIL doesn't support that. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.